# How can I generate a type from a list of types at compile-time?

Tags: c++, mixins, template-meta-programming

I've inherited a [Table Data Gateway](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) implementation and I'm trying to convert some run-time errors to compile-time errors. There is a simple one-to-one mapping between a table and a class, but not all CRUD operations make sense for all types. There is a single "manager" class template that (in a simplified form) looks like

```
template <typename T>
class object_manager
{
public:
    void create(const T&){ /* SQL CREATE */ }
    void update(const T&){ /* SQL UPDATE */ }
    void del(const T&){ /* SQL DELETE */ }
    template <OutIt> OutIt read(OutIt) const {/* SQL SELECT */}
private:
    some_db_connection& m_db;
};
```

I'd like to switch to a mixin type of implementation such that each persistent type has an associated object_manager built up from only the operations that are valid for that object type. I have found that If I break the CRUD functions out into their own classes thusly

```
template <typename T>
class object_manager
{
public:
    typedef T object_type;
protected:
    some_db_connection& m_db;
};

template <typename Base>
class create_mixin : public Base
{
public:
    typedef Base::object_type object_type;
    void create(const object_type&) { /* sql INSERT */ }
};

template <typename Base>
class read_mixin : public Base
{
public:
    typedef Base::object_type object_type;
    template <OutIt> OutIt read(OutIt) const {/* SQL SELECT */}
};

template <typename Base>
class update_mixin : public Base
{
public:
    typedef Base::object_type object_type;
    void update(const object_type&) {/* SQL UPDATE*/}
};

template <typename Base>
class delete_mixin : public Base
{
public:
    typedef Base::object_type object_type;
    void del(const object_type&) {/* SQL DELETE*/}
};
```

Then I am able to generate a type with only the valid operations and thereby find incorrect function calls (e.g. attempts to update an immutable type) at compile type

```
//read-only
read_mixin<object_manager<some_persistent_type>> read_only_mgr;

//un-deletable
create_mixin<read_mixin<update_mixin<object_manager<some_persistent_type>>>> undeletable_mgr;
```

I'd like to get to a point where I am able to generate these object_manager types at compile-time from a boost::mpl::vector, such that I could have a traits class for the persistent type that listed the valid operations.

```
struct op_create;
struct op_read;
struct op_update;
struct op_delete;

template <typename T>
struct my_traits
{
    typedef boost::mpl::vector<op_create, op_read, op_delete> valid_operations;
};
```

The mapping of the somewhat symbolic names (e.g. op_read, op_create, etc.) to the actual mixin classes is trivial but where I'm struggling is how to recreate the types shown in the third code block. I have a vague notion that boost::mpl::inherit_linearly will play a role but it is not yet clear to me how all the pieces fit together.

I should mention that I have access to a relatively modern Boost but not c++11.

Comment: What problm you have exactly? I think that you already answered your question: Use `boost::mpl::inherit_linearly` to inherit from the set of policy classes provided by the `mpl::vector`. if you do that, your type automatically contains the set of functions provided by the types. Where is the problem?